# I'm looking for the code of the hover effect on input in bootsrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, hover, styles

can some tell me how can I create like this hover effect on input using code I mean CSS i don't wanna use bootstrap calss :

```html
<div class="form">
  <div class="input-group mb-3">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
      <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">@</span>
    </div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" aria-label="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to the `form-control` class on input tags for Bootstrap?

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/forms/form-control/

```css
input[type=text]{
  width: 20%;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: solid 1px #c8cacc;
  transition: .04s;
}

input[type=text]:focus{
  outline: solid 4px rgba(95, 160, 250, 0.4);
}
```

```html
<div class="form">
  <div class="input-group mb-3">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
      <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1"></span>
    </div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" aria-label="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
  </div>
```